# Swift : How can I fill the cell when the data is empty?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, uitableview

I'm using tableview. Sometimes my datas getting error, because it is empty data. When I get empty data, I want to return 1 or more cell and show empty data information texts like "No data available!".

Code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var a:Int = 0

        if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0 {
            a = 8
            return a
        }else if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 1{
            a = 4
            return a
        }else if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 2{
            a =  2
            return a
        }else if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 3{
            a = 1
            return a
        }

    return a
}
```

After then 0, all datas are empty. I'm trying to return cell and I'm using this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("knockoutsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KnockoutsTableViewCell

    let item = knockoutsTableArray[indexPath.row]
    if knockoutsTableArray.count == 0{
        cell.dateLabel.text = "Date"
        cell.homeImage.image = UIImage(named: "imagePic.png")
        cell.homeLabel.text = "Empty data!"

    }else{
    if item.playing == true{
        cell.dateLabel.text = item.date
        cell.homeImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(item.homeName)")
    }
    }

    return cell
}
```

**I found the solution and did it thanks to Sethmr. Here is my working code :**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if knockoutsTableArray.count != 0 {
        return knockoutsTableArray.count
    } else{
        if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0{
            return 8
        }else if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 1{
            return 4
        }else if segmentControl.selectedIndex == 2{
            return 2
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }
}
```

Also I moved the `item` value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from the top and It worked. I called the item when It's not empty.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("knockoutsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KnockoutsTableViewCell

    if knockoutsTableArray.count == 0{
        cell.dateLabel.text = "Date"
        cell.homeImage.image = UIImage(named: "imagePic.png")
        cell.homeLabel.text = "Empty data!"

    }else{
    let item = knockoutsTableArray[indexPath.row]
    if item.playing == true{
        cell.dateLabel.text = item.date
        cell.homeImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(item.homeName)")
    }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can't understand where exactly is your problem?

Comment: When my data count is zero, I'm trying to return manually number for cell and return data like above the code. But it's not working. I guess I can't do like that.

Comment: I do not see the code where you trying to trying to return manually number for cell. I only see checking if data is empty array, than you are filling it with empty data content.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of switch statements over if else for readability.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch segmentControl.selectedIndex {
    case 0:
        if knockoutArray.count != 0 {
             return knockoutArray.count
        } else {
             return 1
        } 
    case 1:
        return 4
    case 2:
        return 2
    case 3:
        return 1
    default:
        print("error with selectedIndex")
        return 0
    }
}
```

If all the rows are empty it is because one of the following:
Your segmentControl.selectedIndex = -1 becuase all of itself is unselected or the segmented controller is nil. 
You might not have called tableView.reloadData() after the point in time that this case had changed.

Show me all of cellForRowAtIndexPath, more info about myArray, and anything else that you think could be helpful and I will see what I can do.

Comment: I edited my question. Can I add value in cell without array?

Comment: One thing I see right away, remove this line "knockoutsTableView.reloadData()". Never call tableView.reloadData() from inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. This causes an infinite loop more often than not.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake.

Comment: If I may ask, why are you using segmentControl.selectedIndex to determine the number of cells, but using an array to fill the values of the cells.

Comment: I'm using custom segmented control to jump some other datas.knockoutsTableArray is changing because of that. But some arrays are empty. I want to fill the cell when the array is empty.

Comment: Ok, so which selectedIndex is the one for knockoutArray? I would place the code I wrote below into that return in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115462/discussion-between-sethmr-and-yesman).

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch segmentControl.selectedIndex {
    case 0:
        if knockoutsTableArray.count != 0 {
            return knockoutsTableArray.count
        } else {
            return 1
        } 
    case 1:
        if knockoutsTableArray.count != 0 {
            return 4
        } else {
            return 8
        } 
    case 2:
        return 2
    case 3:
        return 1
    default:
        print("error with selectedIndex")
        return 0
    }
}
```

This seems like what you want.

Comment: Oh your code works! But after then 0, all datas are empty. For example; when I set the second segmented view and if It's empty, I want to return 8. How can I do that for segment control?

Comment: yeah, I was writing the working code. But I didn't use the switch statements :) I understand now. Thanks for the all helps. You are the best! :) I'm editing my working code too btw.